# Converting C++ code to VB.net ( using while )

Tags: c++, vb.net

I'm having trouble parsing some C++ sample code to VB.net ( and yes, i know you won't paste code == do it for me), but i need some guidance.

C++ sample code:

```
int busy=1;
while (busy == 1)
{
hr = pMarker ->GetBusyStatus (cardnum ,&busy);
}
busy=1;

hr = pMarker ->MarkObj (cardnum,i,90.0);
```

VB.net code ( that i have, not working properly)

```
Dim busy As Integer
hr = pMarker.GetBusyStatus(cardnum, busy)

While busy = 1
hr = pMarker.GetBusyStatus(cardnum, busy)
hr = pMarker.MarkObj(cardnum, i, 90.0)
End While
```

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

```
Dim busy As Integer=1

While busy = 1
hr = pMarker.GetBusyStatus(cardnum, busy)
End While

hr = pMarker.MarkObj(cardnum, i, 90.0)
```

I know that i have to use *busy* as ByRef, in order to use it like a pointer... So, how can i manage that?

Comment: Define _"not working properly"_. This snippet doesn't reveal anything that should cause any problems, so you must be specific with what is and what is not working.

Comment: your code is different. you call the function before entering the loop. you do not initialise the busy variable before calling the function the first time. your loop is wrong , you call the markobj function in the loop, the other code does not.

Comment: @dgsomerton yeah, i think my problem is there. I used a online converter and it converted to vb.net, but using a pointer. Somthing like `hr = pMarker.GetBusyStatus(cardnum, New Pointer(Of Integer)(busy))`

Comment: I'm unsure if this will work though: `pMarker ->GetBusyStatus (cardnum ,&busy);` - the C++ method passes the `busy` integer as a pointer, which means that in order to do so in VB.NET you must declare the `GetBusyStatus()`'s second parameter as `ByRef`.

Comment: The C code is initialising busy to 1. it is calling getbusystatus in a loop as long as busy is 1. the function must reset it, it is a reference parameter. once busy is not 1, then the markobj function is called.

Comment: @VisualVincent i've tried it both ways! And, just like you, i don't see any problem in the snippet..

Comment: In order to apply the same functionality in VB.NET you could wrap your integer in a class, then you modify your methods to read the underlying integer of the class they've received through their parameters.

Comment: Edited the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a parameter to be passed by reference in VB.NET, you need to define it as `ByRef` in the method definition - there isn't anything in the calling code that indicates it is passed by reference (unlike the C++ `&` or the C# `ref`).  You didn't show the definition of `GetBusyStatus`, but it should be something like this:

```vb
Public Function GetBusyStatus(cardnum As String, ByRef busy As Integer) As Integer
    '...
    If someCondition Then
        busy = 0
    End If
End Function
```